# Is there anyway to globally configure a credential spec file in docker?

Tags: docker, shinyproxy, rshiny

We currently are in the process of setting up [Shiny Proxy](https://shinyproxy.io/) on a windows server to host a series of R Shiny Web Apps. One of the complications is that some of the apps integrate with SQL Servers. We need to be able to inject credentials into the host windows container so it can use **Windows Authentication** against the SQL Servers. We are not allowed to use SQL Server Authentication accounts with their own passwords.

I have [read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/manage-serviceaccounts) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/gmsa-run-container) on how to do this using Group Managed Service Accounts (gMSA) and credential spec files that are passed to the `docker run` command using the `--security-opt` option.

The problem is that Shiny Proxy has control over starting containers behind the scenes so we are not able to inject the credential spec file into it via the `--security-opt` option.

Is there any other way to configure docker with a credential spec file, perhaps at some global level without explicitly using `docker run --security-opt`?

Comment: I don't know shinyproxy but I see that has is build-in [security](https://shinyproxy.io/documentation/configuration/#authentication)

Comment: This security documentation relates to users accessing the Shiny Proxy Web portal in order to navigate to various apps. It does not however mention anything about how those apps running in docker containers can access outside services such as SQL Server databases